# I have error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType' trying to predict y_pred LogisticRegression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset about patients having diabetes or not with many instances.

Each instance is classified (labelled) with a particular class (binary, 0 or 1)

I have problems when trying to predict Y^

but I have problems :

[image: error text]

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

def load_cvs(filename):
    data = []
    labels = []

    with open(filename,  'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            items = line.split(",")
            data.append([float(items[0]),float(items[1]),float(items[2]),float(items[3]),float(items[4]),float(items[5])])
            labels.append(int(items[6]))
    return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

X,y = load_cvs('diabetes.csv')
df = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv")
#Glucose;BloodPressure;SkinThickness;Insulin;BMI;Age

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.2, random_state=33)

def sigmoid(z):
     return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

def predict(X,w):
    z = np.dot(X,w)
    return sigmoid(z)

def cost(y , y_pred):
    return -np.mean(y * np.log(y_pred) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - y_pred))

def train(X, y, epochs = 1000, lr =0.02):
    X = np.c_[np.ones((X.shape[0], 1)), X]

    w = np.random.randn(X.shape[1])

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        y_pred = predict(X,w)
        error = y_pred - y

    gradient = np.dot(X.T, error) / y.size

    w -= lr * gradient

    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        c = cost(y,y_pred)
        print(f'Epoch{epoch}: cost = {c}')
        return w

w = train(X_train,y_train,epochs=1000, lr=0.02)
X_test=X_test

y_pred = predict(np.c_[np.ones((X_test.shape[0], 1)),  X_test], w)
```

I get this error message:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'`

I changed the code but I still have problems

```
import numpy as np
from random import seed
from random import randrange
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from csv import reader
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

from sklearn import preprocessing

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

def load_cvs(filename):
    data = []
    labels = []

    with open(filename,  'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            items = line.split(",")
            data.append([float(items[0]),float(items[1]),float(items[2]),float(items[3]),float(items[4]),float(items[5])])
            labels.append(int(items[6]))
    return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
seed(1)


col_names = ['Glucose','BloodPressure','SkinThickness','Insulin','BMI','Age','Outcome']
df = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv', header=None, names=col_names)
nandf = df.fillna(value=0)
#nandf = df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
#nandf.head()

feature_cols = ['Glucose','BloodPressure','SkinThickness','Insulin','BMI','Age']
X = nandf[feature_cols] # Features
y = nandf.Outcome # Target variable




X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.2, random_state=16)








def sigmoid(z):
     return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

def predict(X,w):
    z = np.dot(X,w)
    return sigmoid(z)

def cost(y , y_pred):
    return -np.mean(y * np.log(y_pred) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - y_pred))

def train(X, y, epochs = 1000, lr =0.02):
    X = np.c_[np.ones((X.shape[0], 1)), X]

    w = np.random.randn(X.shape[1])

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        y_pred = predict(X,w)
        error = y_pred - y

    gradient = np.dot(X.T, error) / y.size

    w -= lr * gradient

    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        c = cost(y,y_pred)
        print(f'Epoch{epoch}: cost = {c}')
        return w



w = train(X_train,y_train,epochs=1000, lr=0.02)


y_pred = predict(np.c_[np.ones((X_test.shape[0], 1)),  X_test], w) # this line[enter image description here][1]

#print(f'prediction: {y_pred}')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIDYR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIDYR.png)

Comment: You should try to remove all the commented lines and not used imports from your code snippet, that will make it easier to read.

Comment: down to 9 don't know how deal with this mess of images

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have null values in your data, you have to drop or fill them:

```
X, y = load_cvs('diabetes.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
df = df.dropna()  # <- HERE
```

To find rows with null values, use:

```
X, y = load_cvs('diabetes.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
nandf = df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]  # <- HERE
```

Comment: but I don't use df I only use X,y

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter. if `df` contains null values, X and y too.

Comment: still the same problems

Answer (score 0):

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

I think you should try this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error image, the problem is with the `w` in this function.  Did you try to match the error display with your code?

```
def predict(X,w):
    z = np.dot(X,w)
    return sigmoid(z)
```

`w` is `None`, which can't be using in math (that should be obvious!)

Where does `w` come from?

```
w = train(X_train,y_train,epochs=1000, lr=0.02)
```

`train` has one `return` statement in an `if`.  What if that `if` isn't true?  What does `train` return then?

It's your code, and it's your responsibility to test each piece.